# Restart screenshot process on Mac OS

Tags: macos, screenshot, kill

OSX has simple and useful screenshot hotkeys. Often though they stop working for me.

I found that killing the screenshot process through Activity Monitor and re-running it helped and was quicker than restarting my laptop..

Unfortunately some time past since I did that last and I forgot which process it was -

**Which process is it? and how would I restart it after I kill it?**

Comment: Possible dupe: [What process is tied to shortcut screenshots in OSX?](//superuser.com/q/588886)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!
Force kill `pboard` through Activity Monitor - no need to restart it manually, it does so immediately by itself